# change breadcrumb on view div load in YII2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

We are using this code in layouts/main.php to create breadcrumb

```
 Breadcrumbs::widget([
  'homeLink' => [ //''label=>'',
                  'label' => Yii::t('yii', ''),
                  //1 'url' =>['about']
             ],
  'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ?  $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
 ])
```

And on view page we are initializing this breadcrumb by this:

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' =>$valcc22, 
                    'template' => "<div>{link}",'url'=> $newlinkurl ];
                $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' =>' >> ', 
                    'template' => "{link}", ];
```

Now problem is, On view we are reloading div based on search, For this we are using this piece of code

```
  var turl=window.location.href+" #maincontainer"; //load the fragment only
$("#maincontainer").load(turl,{'from': 'ajax'},function(response, status, xhr){
       });
```

It's working fine but breadcrumb is not refreshed. Even we all-ready put breadcrumb code in maincontainer div, it's not refreshing the breadcrumb.

Please tell me whats the problem here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use ajax i think is correct not refresh the entire page (breadcrumbs included) in you want refresh the page why you don'tuse a controller  action and  a render function. ?